# git log --pretty with list of files?

Tags: git

I am trying to use 'git log --pretty=tformat' to create xml file log. However I have problem getting the list of file for each commit.

for example:
I use this command

```
$echo '<?xml version="1.0"?>' > out.xml
$echo '<git>' >> out.xml
$git log   --pretty=tformat:'    <commit>%n        <h1>%s</h1>%n    </commit>'  --name-only  >> out.xml
$echo '</git>'>> out.xml
```

the output:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<git>
    <commit>
        <h1>Commit 1</h1>
    </commit>
    <commit>
        <h1>Commit 2</h1>
    </commit>
    <commit>
        <h1>Commit 3</h1>
    </commit>
</git>
```

I want to add tag in side the commit tag with the list of files so my final output look like this

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <git>
        <commit>
            <h1>Commit 1</h1>
            <list>file1</list>
        </commit>
        <commit>
            <h1>Commit 2</h1>
            <list>file2</list>
        </commit>
        <commit>
            <h1>Commit 3</h1>
            <list>file3</list>
        </commit>
    </git>
```

I did try --name-only it will list the file but cannot format the output.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: A bit unrelated to the actual problem, but constructing XML in cases like this may be a bit simpler if you have a look at xml2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might not be what you're looking for, but it's easy to script. The following is one implementation, inefficient but functional. Careful running it: It will operate on your entire history. Change the second line to `revlist=$(git rev-list -10 HEAD)` to see it work on just the last 10 commits. It also assumes you want older commits at the bottom of the file, per your example above. Add a `--reverse` flag to `git rev-list` if you'd prefer chronological order:

```
#!/bin/sh
revlist=$(git rev-list HEAD)
(
    echo '<?xml version="1.0"?>'
    echo '<git>'
    for rev in $revlist
    do
            files=$(git log -1 --pretty="format:" --name-only $rev)
            echo '    <commit>\n        <h1>\c'
            echo "$(git log -1 --pretty="%s" $rev)\c"
            echo '</h1>'
            for file in $files
            do
                    echo "        <list>$file</list>"
            done
            echo '    </commit>'
    done
    echo '</git>'
) > out.xml
```

Comment: nice one! Is there a way to get the information such as whether the file was modified or deleted or added?

Comment: @NikhilGupta: Yeah, try replacing `--name-only` with `--name-status`. The short codes printed before the file names are designed to be machine parseable. Search [this page](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-log.html) for "--diff-filter" to see what the codes mean. Then just add some logic to process those codes, and there you go.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get all file information as a single text field with some minor manipulation of the file afterwards (moving the first two rows to the end of the file) with the following powershell script: (replacing REPONAME with the name of the repository, could be automated further.)

```
git --git-dir <path to repository> log --name-only --pretty=format:"]]></files>%n</commit>%n<commit>%n<repo>REPONAME</repo>%n<hash>%H</hash>%n<author>%an</author>%n<dt>%ct</dt>%n<subject><![CDATA[%s]]></subject>%n<files><![CDATA[" | Out-File REPONAME.xml
$x = get-content REPONAME.xml
@("<gitrepo>") + $x[2..$x.count] + $x[0..1] + @("</gitrepo>") | set-content REPONAME.xml
```

To split up the files I had to do some further processing in the database (splitting newline etc), but that is outside the scope of this answer.

This outputs a file which looks like:

```
<gitrepo>
<commit>
<repo>REPONAME</repo>
<hash>388d77493cb2b4d3260cd12b1adcf23e947755f4</hash>
<author>Some Guy</author>
<dt>1401802177</dt>
<subject><![CDATA[Comments added to files]]></subject>
<files><![CDATA[
src/aben/blanksid.w
src/aben/c_typop.w
src/aben/freg.w
src/aben/freskid.w
src/aben/grit5.w
src/aben/grokli.w

]]></files>
</commit>
</gitrepo>
```