# save filename from Git into an XML file

Tags: git

I would like to create an XML file that includes data resulted from "git log" command like Commit Hash, Author Name, and File Name.

I know that I can use `git log --pretty=format:"%h - %an"` to get the Commit Hash and Author Name. But, I'm wondering if there is an option to get the File Name?

I *don't* want to use `git log --name-only`, `git log --name-status` or `git log --stat` because they give me other information I don't need for.

Is there anyway to easily get just the File Name ?

Comment: `git log --pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit` like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want filename and nothing else, use this command:

```
git log --pretty="format:" --name-only
```

It's actually pretty easy to parse `git log` into XML. Checkout [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11093911/git-log-pretty-with-list-of-files/11094170#11094170) for an example shell script.